# как запретить изменение размера таблицы в зависимости от содержимого

Tags: html, css, табличная-верстка

Мне нужно уравнить ширину каждой ячейки

```css
.grid {
width:100%;
color:#333;
font-family:sans-serif;
}
.grid td {
background:#eee;
border:1px solid #ccc;
padding:2px;
transition:all .5s;
}
.grid td:first-child {
border-radius:3px 0 0 3px;
}
.grid td:last-child {
border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}
.grid td:hover {
background:#41B3FF;
border:1px solid #006EB8;
cursor:pointer;
color:#00426E;
}
```

```html
Как сделать 3 человека равными?
<table class="grid" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td>Я бедный.</td>
    <td>Я самый богатый! А в чем причина?</td>
    <td>Я состоятелный.</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте - `table-layout: fixed;` таблица делится на колонки равной ширины.  Для корректной работы этого значения обязательно должна быть задана ширина таблицы.

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

table{
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
td{
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Я бедный.</td>
    <td>Я самый богатый! А в чем причина?</td>
    <td>Я состоятелный.</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Я бедный.</td>
    <td>Я самый богатый! А в чем причина?</td>
    <td>Я состоятелный.</td>
     <td>Я состоятелный.</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.grid {
width:100%;
color:#333;
font-family:sans-serif;
}
.grid td {
background:#eee;
border:1px solid #ccc;
padding:2px;
transition:all .5s;
width:33%;
}
.grid td:first-child {
border-radius:3px 0 0 3px;
}
.grid td:last-child {
border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}
.grid td:hover {
background:#41B3FF;
border:1px solid #006EB8;
cursor:pointer;
color:#00426E;
}
```

```html
Укажите width для td
<table class="grid" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td>Я бедный.</td>
    <td>Я самый богатый! А в чем причина?</td>
    <td>Я состоятелный.</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: ха, а если у меня их больше 3x?

Comment: ну мне кажется, универсального варианта тут нет. для того чтобы использовать переменные в css используются препроцессоры.